# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float' with Math.Pow()

Tags: c#

Hi I am making a calculate the present value of a future amount but in my formula I keep getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).I am not sure as to how to fix this.
Any help would be appreciated

```
   public static float PresentValue(float futureValue, float rate, int years)
   {
          float presentValue;
          presentValue = futureValue / Math.Pow(1 + rate, years);

          return presentValue;
   }
```

Comment: The error message says a lot.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are `float`, but the method `Math.Pow` returns a `double`. Hence you need explicit conversion to be performed on the result of the method.

```
presentValue = futureValue / (float)Math.Pow(1 + rate, years);
```

Note: `Math.Pow` also takes `double` as parameters, but still it works. That's because implicit conversion is taking place. Because `double` can represent every possible value of a `float` but reverse isn't true.

Read about `Implicit` and `Explicit` conversions

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code it and worked for me:

```
(float)Math.Round(amount);
```